# При попытке получить свойства из обобщенного интерфейса через dynamic - ошибка: Использование типа dynamic в лямбде запрещено

Tags: c#, наследование, blazor, dynamic, cast

Пытаюсь использовать `dynamic` тип, чтобы достать свойства `ValueFrom` и `ValueTo` из обобщенного интерфейса `IRuleConfig<T>`. Когда ссылаюсь на переменную типа `dynamic` в лямбде `@bind-Value` и запускаю билд, то получаю сообщение:

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Можно ли обойти эту ошибку, либо указать в коде прямо, что хочу получить эти свойства из обобщенного интерфейса, а не из обычного?
Прилагаю подробный код

```
public interface IRuleConfig : ITextBuilderRule
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public bool MinValue { get; set; }
    public bool MaxValue { get; set; }
    public string LabelFrom { get; }
    public string LabelTo { get; }
}
public interface IRuleConfig<T> : IRuleConfig {
    public T ValueFrom { get; set; }
    public T ValueTo { get; set; }

}
public class ImplementRule<T> : IRuleConfig<T>
{
    private T _deltaFrom;
    private T _deltaTo;

    public T ValueFrom { get; set; }
    public T ValueTo { get; set; }
    public string LabelFrom { get => "Label1"; }
    public string LabelTo { get => "Label2"; }
    public int TypeValues { get; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public bool MinValue { get; set; }
    public bool MaxValue { get; set; }

    public ImplementRule(T From, T To)
    {
        _From = From;            
        _To = To;

        ValueFrom = From;            
        ValueTo = To;
    }
 }

Type Construct()
{
    Type type = CoreAssembly.GetType($"ImplementRule`1");
    Type[] typeArgs = { type.GetProperty("TypeValues").PropertyType };
    return type.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
}

List<TextBuilderTemplate> TextsByRule= new List<TextBuilderTemplate>(){
    new TextBuilderTemplate { Rule = Activator.CreateInstance(Construct(), 0, 0) as IRuleConfig }}
```

```
@for (var a = 0; a < TextsByRule.Count; a++)
{
    var i = a;
    dynamic d = TextsByRule[i].Rule;
    <MudItem xs="4">
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="@TextsByRule[i].Template" Class="float-left w-100" Label="Text" />
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="8">
        <MudCheckBox  @bind-Checked="@TextsByRule[i].Rule.MinValue" Class="float-left my-5" Label="MinValue" />
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="@d.ValueFrom" Disabled="@TextsByRule[i].Rule.MinValue" Class="float-left px-5 w-25" Label="@SelectedRule.LabelFrom" />
        <MudCheckBox  @bind-Checked="@TextsByRule[i].Rule.MaxValue" Class="float-left my-5" Label="MaxValue" />
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="@d.ValueTo" Disabled="@TextsByRule[i].Rule.MaxValue" Class="float-left px-5 w-25" Label="@SelectedRule.LabelTo" />
    </MudItem>
}
```

[image: Интерфейсы]

[image: обращение к свойствам]

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: А зачем вообще эти все пляски с динамичесеим созданием типа, если тип - ваш код? Как вы вообще попали в такую ситуацию, что вам потребовалась рефлексия?

Comment: при выполнении цикла for у меня подсталяется тип обобщенного интерфейса - но ДО билда у меня ведь тип НЕобобщенного интерфейса, поэтому пытаюсь привести к dynamic и  от  него обращатся к ValueFrom, ValueTo.


Рефлексию использую потому что мои интерфейсы и их реализации лежат  в отдельном проекте и  через Type.GetType() к ним не достучатся, нужно иметь правильную сборку вместо Type и указывать полный путь в GetType()

Comment: Что мешает подключить отдельный проект через Package Reference? То есть добавляем ссылку на вторую сборку, добавляем `using МойНеймспейс_Сборки;` и видим все публичные типы.

Comment: уже подключен
<ItemGroup>
 <ProjectReference Include="..\солюшен.проект\солюшен.проект.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

 и неймспейс тоже используется,
@using солюшен.Core.Models.TextBuilder.Abstractions
 но по какой-то причине используется Assembly в которой я вызываю тип а не тот на который референс.
Главное найти способ  вызывать свойства с обобщенного интерфеса - когда Rule имеет  тип необобщенного без нужных свойств

Comment: `но по какой-то причине используется Assembly` интересно, по какой? Короч, если кратко, `dynamic` (как вы уже поняли) при приведении к интерфейсу, у которого нет свойства, которое вам нужно - не поможет. Если вы через рефлексию создали (недоступный на этапе компиляции) тип, то только рефлексия вам поможет работать с инстансом. А еще лучше - создавайте типы нормально когда это возможно, без рефлексии. Сами себе усложняете код без видимых на то причин. А еще рефлексия - это очень медленно работает.

Comment: Пока без рефлискии не обойтись(
Придумал конвертор он возращает интерфейс с нужным дженериком
но вместо "T" нужно указать тип который в switch возращается - реально ли укзать тип для "T"?

public IRuleConfig<T> CastGenericType(IRuleConfig Rule) =>
        Rule.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].Name switch
        {
            "Double" => (IRuleConfig<double>)Rule,
            "Int" => (IRuleConfig<int>)Rule,
            _ => (IRuleConfig<object>)Rule
        };

Comment: Указать явно в коде можно только то, что известно на этапе компиляции. Дженерики известны на этапе компиляции. Если это не так, значит это рефлексия. Если надо форкнуть через свич и вернуть из метода, то вы например можете возвращать свой какой-то тип, или вообще запаковать в `object` нужное свойство, или отдать вьюхе как `string`. Вариантов много, но изврат в вашей архитектуре начался на этапе проектирования модели данных. Выглядит она у вас, мягко говоря, странно. Ну или я чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось на стороне UI - создал дочерние компоненты через builder.OpenComponent() в которых пробросил свойство с типом необобщенного интерфейса и в дочернем  компоненте указал нужный дженерик